# How to recolor buttons in Cordova with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I try to create buttons that recolor themselves when clicked. My code for that looks as the follows:

```
function foo(){
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerText = i;
        btn.id = "testbutton" + i;
        (function(btnID){
            btn.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
                document.getElementById(btnID).style.backgroundColor = "red";
        })})(btn.id);
        (function(){
            btn.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
                doSomethingElse();
        })})();
        docFrag.appendChild(btn);
    }
    document.getElementById("buttonContainer").appendChild(docFrag);
}
```

It does work in my browser, but when I deploy my code to an emulator it simply skips the coloring part or doesn't do it at all. The reason I use "mousedown" is that I want the buttons to make something else on "mouseup". I previously tried doing both the recoloring as well as the other function on "clicked" but it would then skip the recoloring entirely, since the new function would overwrite the previous work.

Comment: Side note; there is no reason to perform a lookup by id for the button the event is bound to.  Both `this` and, if you pass it in, the `event.target` will both point to the button the event originated from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mobile there is no mouse so "mousedown" event doesn't exist.

I guess you should use instead or also "touchstart" and "touchend".

=> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent